# NGINX forwarding on DO: mup issues

Tags: meteor, nginx, meteor-up

There have been many posts about NGINX and Meteor.js (using mup). However, none of them seemed to solve for my case. I can't get the NGINX vhost to forward it correctly to where my app lives on my DigitalOcean droplet.

Here's my mup.json:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": <IP-address>,
      "username": "root",
      "password": <root pwd>
    }
  ],
  "setupMongo": true,
  "setupNode": true,
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",
  "setupPhantom": true,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "appName": myapp,
  "app": ".",
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://localhost",
    "PORT" : 3000,
    "METEOR_ENV": "development"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Then, on my droplet, I have deleted `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and created: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.com.conf` together with a sym-link in sites-available, that looks like:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           myapp.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

After restarting NGINX, when I locally do `mup deploy` it cannot deploy with the message `Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused` i.e. the app cannot be connected to on the droplet.

I've been banging my head against the wall for some days, any ideas what can be the issue?

Comment: Anybody an idea? I've tried every answer available on the internet, but none seem to work. It should be trivial to forward it to the correct port, but it refuses to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I had the exact same setup & problem, and even though I “solved it”, I never found out why it didn't work before. I basically kept swapping back and fourth between port 80 and port 3000 in my mup.js env: {}. At first it worked with port 80, then I got *nginx 502 Bad Gateway meteor* the next day — then I tried port env: { 3000 }  (just like localhost in Nginx conf) — it didn't work. Then I deleted my Meteor App locally, installed a new version, and tried once more with port env: {3000} — and just like that it worked. I hate not knowing why something works :-p